# creating jtable inside a translucent swing window

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to create a translucent swing window in java with a table and a button in it.. The table contents are imported from a xml file.. My code is this

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class Swings extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public File xml = null;
    public Document dom = null;
    public JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    public DefaultTableModel model;
    public JTable jTable1;
    public JButton update_button;

    public Swings() {
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // statusLabel.setSize(350,100);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
                    final int R = 220;
                    final int G = 220;
                    final int B = 250;
                    Paint p = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(R, G, B, 0), 0.0f, getHeight(), new Color(R, G, B, 255), true);
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    g2d.setPaint(p);
                    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                    Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 45);
                    g2d.setFont(font);
                    g2d.Color(Color.red);
                    g2d.drawString("Service Now Notification", 40, 120);
                }
            }
        };
        xml = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Html1.xml");
        installGUI();
        setContentPane(panel);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(jtable1);
        add(update_button);
    }

    public void installGUI() {
        Container ctr = getContentPane();
        ctr.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        model = new DefaultTableModel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        // creates an instance of the table class and sets it up in a scrollpane
        jTable1 = new JTable(model);
        jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTable1);
        ctr.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, jScrollPane1);
        // add some columns
        model.addColumn("Number");
        model.addColumn("Priority");
        model.addColumn("State");
        model.addColumn("Assigned");
        model.addColumn("Short_desc");
        model.addColumn("Task");
        if (xml.exists() && xml.length() != 0) {
            dom = parseFile(xml);
            insertTableRows(model, dom);
        }
    }

    // creates an instance of a Document object
    public Document parseFile(File file) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            dom = (Document) builder.parse(file);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dom;
    }

    public void insertTableRows(DefaultTableModel tableModel, Document doc) {
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList list = root.getElementsByTagName("MS");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); ++i) {
            Element e = (Element) list.item(i);
            if (e.getNodeType() == Element.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Object[] row = { getArticleInfo("S", e) };
                tableModel.addRow(row);
            }
        }
        tableModel.fireTableStructureChanged();
        tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public Object getArticleInfo(String tagName, Element elem) {
        NodeList list = elem.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); ++i) {
            Node node = (Node) list.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Node child = (Node) node.getFirstChild();
                return child.getTextContent().trim();
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        boolean isPerPixelTranslucencySupported = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT);
        if (!isPerPixelTranslucencySupported) {
            System.out.println("Per-pixel translucency is not supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Swing gtw = new Swing();
                // gtw.runn();
                gtw.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The xml file content is this:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
    <Obj RefId="0">
        <TN RefId="0">
            <T>Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T> 
            <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T> 
            <T>System.Object</T> 
        </TN>
        <MS>
            <S N="Number">INC0811168</S> 
            <S N="Priority">2 - High</S> 
            <S N="State">Assigned</S> 
            <S N="Assigned">New</S> 
            <S N="Short_desc">Review Ad-Hoc Service Request for Lavon A Gudmundson</S> 
            <S N="Task">Catalog Task</S> 
        </MS>
    </Obj>
</Objs>
```

I am getting a translucent notification window with a button as the output..

Comment: And what's your current problem?

Comment: I need to get the contents from xml file to be displayed in the table in the swing window

Comment: `JTable` is not a good fit for XML, a `JTree` would be a better choice

Comment: You should not be calling the `fireXxx` methods from outside the of the model context, they are for the models use, not yours (unless you within the model's context, then that's a different story)

Comment: You can create entities according to xml structure, then load them from xml file, and use as rows in `JTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the transparent window for a moment (as it seems you have that figured out), there are basically two ways to do what you want to achieve, based on what it is you want to achieve, however, the basic means of reading the XML file remains the same...

You can either, preload the XML data into matching POJO and add them into some kind structure of management (like a `List` for example) and apply these values to the `TableModel` or wrap the `TableModel` model around the XML document itself and let it manage the entire process...

This example does the later, but it wouldn't take much to separate the loading process and do the former...

[image: XMLTable]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLTableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new XMLTableExample();
    }

    public XMLTableExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JTable table = new JTable();
                try {
                    table.setModel(new XMLTableModel(new File("Html1.xml")));
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class XMLTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        protected static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
            "Number",
            "Priority",
            "State",
            "Assigned",
            "Description",
            "Task"
        };
        private List<MSEntity> rows;

        public XMLTableModel(File file) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
            rows = new ArrayList<>(25);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = db.parse(file);

            setDocument(dom);
        }

        protected String getMSValue(Node msNode, String name) throws XPathExpressionException {
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("S[@N='" + name + "']");
            Node sNode = (Node)expression.evaluate(msNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
            return sNode != null ? sNode.getTextContent() : null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return String.class;
        }

        public MSEntity getEntityAtRow(int row) {
            return rows.get(row);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            MSEntity entity = getEntityAtRow(rowIndex);
            Object value = null;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = entity.getNumber();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = entity.getPriority();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value = entity.getState();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    value = entity.getAssigned();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    value = entity.getDesc();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    value = entity.getTask();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        public void setDocument(Document dom) throws XPathExpressionException {

            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/Objs/Obj/MS");
            NodeList nl = (NodeList)expression.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int index = 0; index < nl.getLength(); index++) {
                Node node = nl.item(index);
                String number = getMSValue(node, "Number");
                String priority = getMSValue(node, "Priority");
                String state = getMSValue(node, "State");
                String assigned = getMSValue(node, "Assigned");
                String desc = getMSValue(node, "Short_desc");
                String task = getMSValue(node, "Task");

                MSEntity entity = new MSEntity(number, priority, state, assigned, desc, task);
                rows.add(entity);
            }

            fireTableDataChanged();

        }

        public class MSEntity {
            private final String number;
            private final String priority;
            private final String state;
            private final String assigned;
            private final String desc;
            private final String task;

            public MSEntity(String number, String priority, String state, String assigned, String desc, String task) {
                this.number = number;
                this.priority = priority;
                this.state = state;
                this.assigned = assigned;
                this.desc = desc;
                this.task = task;
            }

            public String getAssigned() {
                return assigned;
            }

            public String getDesc() {
                return desc;
            }

            public String getNumber() {
                return number;
            }

            public String getPriority() {
                return priority;
            }

            public String getState() {
                return state;
            }

            public String getTask() {
                return task;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Some notes you might like to know about your transparent approach...the `JScrollPane` is opaque, the `JViewport` is opaque and the `JTable` is opaque.  If your hoping to see threw these components, you are going to have to change these states

Comment: I need to add a button to this too